# Difference between HMAC-SHA1(key, msg) vs SHA1(key + msg)

Tags: algorithm-design, hmac, sha-1

Is there any practical difference from using `HMAC-SHA1(key, msg)` vs `SHA1(key + msg)` as a way to verify the authenticity/integrity of a certain message? Note that the plus sign means string concatenation in this context

Am I losing out on some esoteric detail that the `HMAC-SHA1` offers in terms of mathematical immunity to cryptanalysis? Or do both approaches basically do the same thing?

Ive looked through the basic descriptions of both algorithms. And although `HMAC-SHA1` seems to do some fancy things with padding and other stuff, I fail to understand any importance. To me both `HMAC-SHA1(key, msg)` & `SHA1(key + msg)` carry essentially the same strength/resistance against attacks aside from superficial details

How am I wrong, What am I missing?

Comment: @octus 
At the risk of sounding like a clown, what exactly does the double pipe `||` in H(k||x) mean? Its definitely not the "given that" `|` found in probability notation. And quick google search has yielded nothing

Comment: It means string concatenation.

Comment: While concatenation is the common usage,  in crypto || is often used to mean "mapped injectively into a single string". Now, this might be the same thing, but only if the first parameter does not 'overflow' some designated datatype. A lot of (admittedly rather petty) attacks exist based on the fact when concatenating $A||0B = A0||B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right off the bat, SHA1(key + msg) is vulnerable to length extension attacks. That is, if I know SHA1(key + msg) I can use that to compute SHA1(key + msg + anything I'd like to add here) without having to know the key.